# how can set image on label text using coretext

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, image

i want to set image on backside on UILabel text using CoreText Kit..please show this image -====> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh40P.png)

how to set this type format using CoreText Kit

Comment: you can add image to background of UILabel

Answer (score 0):

Look [Core Text Tutorial for iOS: Making a Magazine App](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app) in

> Drawing Images in Core Text
>
> Basically Core Text does not have possibility to draw images. However,
> since it’s a layout engine, what it can do is leave an empty space
> where you want to draw a picture. And since your code is already
> inside a drawRect: method, drawing an image yourself is easy...

chapter

Comment: I try... not working
I want to set image using coreText Kit Framework.. please suggest